# is this a way to search substring and ignore specific cells? c#

Tags: c#, string

I need to search a string which, for example, looks like this: `113312312`, within
in a string looking like `11211201222110`.

The meaning is to look for the substring in the original. Note where the `3` appears in the substring can be *anything* in the original.

original : `111222121212`

```
scenario 1:  func(131222121212) return true
scenario 2:  func(333222) return true
scenario 3:  func(3333333333) return true
scenario 4:  func(333333333333) return true
scenario 5:  func(233333333333) return false
```

Comment: It is unclear what the expected input and output is. It is also confusing that you want to ingore the 3. If you want to do that, just cut them out of the string you want to search.

Comment: Provide more clarification

Comment: @SushantYelpale ok , i write some more , hope its clear.

Comment: @Christopher i know its possible this way, i just want to know if that a library who do it, and can be more efficient then me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public bool match(string original, string pattern)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(original)) return false;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern)) return false;
    if (pattern.Length > original.Length) return false;

    pattern = "^" + pattern.Replace("3", @"\d");
    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(original, pattern);
}
```

See it work:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/LYbdrj

Comment: From my understanding (which is based on guessing), this is the way to go. Missing from the answer I'd any explanation (which is why I'm not upvoting). What @joelcoehoorn is doing is taking the 3s in your pattern and converting them to a "\d" regex token. The "\d" will match any digit. Then he's prefacing the pattern with a "^" which says: "match from the beginning of the string". Once that's done, he uses standard Regex tools and the constructed patter to do the matching

Comment: just a little edit: i removed the "^" and then it worked.